# How can I include characters like "@" or "." in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wildcard

When users signup for a site and have spaces, periods, or @ in the usernames it seems to create problems. How can I include these characters?

Comment: What do you mean by "it _seems_ to create problems"?

Comment: hi Pete, you need to provide much more information if you wish to get an answer.  Take some of your tags and explain in your text what you wish to do

Comment: Show some code and your database schema.

Comment: Why would you do that? What's the point?

Comment: I think you guys went a little downvote crazy on this one, lol. He's just a 16 year old kid. One or two downvotes and a close would have sufficed. Plus he does accept and upvote (although this could be improved on his part).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL couldn't care less about characters in a username or password, unless you're not constructing your query properly:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$quoted_pass = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$quoted_user = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$quoted_pass', '$quoted_user');
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_affected_rows($result) != 1) {
   die("User record not created");
}
```